# What is the short-cut key to jump to declaration in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

In visual studio it 's easier to push F12 button to jump to a declaration of a function or variable when editing C/C++  code.

Is there a short-cut key in emacs to do that?

Comment: The question is too broad, IMO. The answers range from Imenu to various tags commands, and onward to any number of 3rd-party features. I'd say start with the Emacs manual...

Answer (score 31):

Well, it's a bit more involved than that.

By default, Emacs doesn't "know" about function declarations for C or C++ code. First, obtain [Exuberant Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/). Then, use command `etags` (ctags for Emacs) on your source code. A file named `TAGS` will be generated.

Then, while editing your source code, when you want to jump to a declaration, press <kbd>M-.</kbd> (meta and dot, or alt and dot on modern keyboards). At first, Emacs will ask you for location of your tags file. Point it to the one you generated and afterwards navigation will be automatic.

I'd suggest reading [Emacswiki article about tags](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsTags) for a better understanding of this functionality.

The newest version of Emacs (23.2) comes with [CEDET](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/) integrated, which has more advanced features for C and C++ navigation, but it can be a bit difficult to set up right, so read more about it if you're interested.

Comment: How to make Emacs jump to the definition of a function (its implementation) rather than its declaration (it's prototype typically in a header file)? I ran ctags with `ctags -R -e --c-kinds=cdefglmnpstuvx`.

Comment: Also worthy of mention is the combo `M-*`, which will allow you return to where you started from (the point where you used `M-.`). You can use both recursively.

Answer (score 20):

M-. key will take you to the function definition emacs.

Comment: I this should be the right answer ,
I also discovered that command by mistake :))

Comment: The [Emacs tags article](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsTags) and the [tags file article](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TagsFile#tags_file) provide more information on this command, note that you need to have emacs create the TAGS file, e.g,. using `etags mycodefile.c` from the command line.

Comment: ...and how do I jump back to where I came from?

Comment: @ThomasSebastian I've heard M-, works for that

Answer (score 14):

As others have said there is no built-in universal solution for this in emacs. That said, after having this functionality in IntelliJ I wanted it in emacs too so I made [Dumb Jump](https://github.com/jacktasia/dumb-jump).

Right now [Dumb Jump](https://github.com/jacktasia/dumb-jump) has basic support for:

- JavaScript
- Emacs Lisp
- Python
- Go
- PHP
- Ruby
- Faust
- and more... (over 20 now)

It's available via [MELPA](http://melpa.org/#/dumb-jump) and is actively being developed.

Answer (score 7):

There are multiple ways to do this. As darioo mentioned, Ctags is one, but it goes to the definition by default (which might work for you). Looking further, though, you can see that prefixing `M-.`(ie, `C-u M-.`) will take you to the next tag match (which is often the declaration). There is also a `--declarations` option, but Exuberant Ctags doesn't seem to support it.

CEDET is another option, but in my experience, it's still not ready for production. Often times in C++ `semantic-ia-fast-jump` will go to forward declarations instead of the definition or the declaration.