# Where is R's C-level PROTECT macro defined?

Tags: c, r, macros

R's source files are peppered with calls to the `PROTECT()` and `UNPROTECT()` macros, which extend and then withdraw protection of R objects from garbage collection. (See, e.g., [this section](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/C-interface.html#calling-c) of Hadley Wickham's Advanced R for some discussion of their role.)

I've grep'd R's sources to find where those might be defined, but haven't gotten very far. grep'ing the `src` directory for `#define PROTECT` finds me [these lines in `src/include/Rinternals.h`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/include/Rinternals.h#L653-L656):

```
/* Pointer Protection and Unprotection */
#define PROTECT(s)  Rf_protect(s)
#define UNPROTECT(n)    Rf_unprotect(n)
#define UNPROTECT_PTR(s)    Rf_unprotect_ptr(s)
```

I then grep `Rf_protect` to learn where *it* is defined, and run into a dead end. It's only ever even appears (4 times) in this same file, and none of them give me a clue to what its value is.

Clearly I'm missing something fundamental. What is it and/or where should I look to see what code a call to `PROTECT()` expands into?

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569730/where-do-i-find-the-definition-of-rf-protect-in-rs-sources and https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2006-February/036459.html

Comment: @tonysdg Thanks. That's what I was missing. (I had seen that, and  made the mistake of grep'ing `#include protect`, thinking it too was a macro, rather than grep'ing `SEXP protect`, which is what was needed.)

Comment: @TheTime I use Emacs, mostly. [Looks like](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759211/what-is-the-short-cut-key-to-jump-to-declaration-in-emacs) it might support the sort of functionality you describe, with some setup. What editor are you on?

Comment: @TheTime Holy cow! That's terrific! Just for the record, here on Windows, [following these instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738219/how-to-use-shell-magic-to-create-a-recursive-etags-using-gnu-etags), I did `dir /b /s *.c *.h | etags -` from the top of R's source directory. Constructing the entire `TAGS` file took ~1 second, after which `M-.` got me the 'Find tag' dialogue, and I was off and running. Thanks a bunch.